# My dog only pees in the house when I'm not home

Tags: dogs, behavior, toilet-training, anxiety

My 13 month old dog started peeing in the house again after being house trained.  He would *only* do it at night (when I was asleep) or when I would go out.  At first it seemed just like an accident, but when it started happening more consistently (even when walked immediately before bed or right before I left) I switched to crate training.

He's been mostly fine with the crate, though he does sometimes get stressed in there.  After a month, I decided to try seeing if the habit was broken.  I left him alone in the house (not in the crate) for about 20 minutes to run an errand, and when I got back he had peed 3 times.

If he's only peeing in the house when I'm not there to catch him, how do I correct the behavior?  Or should I just continue to leave him in his crate?  He doesn't have this problem  when I'm home (and awake), even if he's unsupervised or if it's been a while since his last walk.

---

I don't have access to comment, so to answer your question, Jeremy, I don't know if he has peed in the house while left alone with others.  I live alone, so if he's home with someone it's usually me.  My sister dogsat for him one weekend, and he definitely peed while I was gone, though she said she didn't see him do it (it might have been overnight or when she was out as well).

Comment: What about with other people? Will he do it if someone else besides you is alone with him?

Comment: Is it only pee? 3 times within 20 minutes seems like a health problem, although I have been told that dogs will save their pee so they can mark in multiple territories. If you don't think it could be a bladder infection of some sort, try keeping track of where he pees - it might be territorial. If so, I suggest taking steps towards showing that YOU are the owner of the house (ensure you walk in the house before your dog, ect..)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my dog peeing in the house when we're not home](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2952/why-is-my-dog-peeing-in-the-house-when-were-not-home)

Answer (score -2):

I’m a 62 year old male, reflecting on a dog I owned in the 1970’s who had a similar issue, I understand your question, and have an answer that will make your dog completely happy. In looking back, I was a bad dog owner because I didn’t understand what my dog needed, from a psychological perspective. Listening to an animal behavior expert explain that a dog is a pack animal and is totally dependant on the group dynamic for social well being, leaving your dog alone is the dog equivalent of complete despair.

Here is my version of what your dog is thinking [“Can you believe it, she left me alone, again! I would never leave her alone so why does she keep doing this to me? OK, I’m pissed now, and will start doing things that communicate how upset I truly am over being left alone!]

Here is your answer: your dog needs a companion when you are not there.  Another dog is your best answer, your dog will also eventually accept a cat as a companion, but will never accept being left alone without psychological damage.